# How do I get my computer to use WDDM 1.1 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I am trying to get started with programming for Windows Phone 7, but I cannot deploy to the emulator unless I have WDDM 1.1.

I only have WDDM 1.0 according to dxdiag. I am running on an HP dv6736 with an NVIDIA GeForce 7150M GPU. I have searched for hours and tried several drivers. It seems NVIDIA has not released updated drivers for this chipset.

Is there a way around this, or am I stuck with WDDM 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the modded drivers

- [Windows 7 32-bit](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27279-v25947-windows-7vista-32bit-hpcompaq-oem-inf/)
- [Windows 7 64-bit](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27280-v25947-windows-7vista-64bit-hpcompaq-oem-inf/)

If these don't work then you're stuck out.

Comment: It looks like I am stuck, then. Too bad... Thanks though! I don't want to accept because I can't confirm it's the correct answer...if others can confirm, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Take your time @joe